# How do I boost the score of speicifc classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails

I have 3 classes, Products, Reviews, Categories.
When someone searches, I would like the categories to show up first, then Reviews, then Categories.
My first thought is to boost the score of each class. The [sunspot documentation](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Setting-up-classes-for-search-and-indexing#boost)
describes how to do this

```
Sunspot.setup(Review) do
    boost 1.2
end
```

but I have no idea where to put this and I'd need to do it for each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should go into your index declaration, as you don't need to do it in query time. For example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  seachable do
    text :title
    boost 1.3
  end
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  seachable do
    text :author
    boost 1.2
  end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  seachable do
    text :name
    boost 1.1
  end
end
```